# Is there an approximate formula for the discriminant of a sparse polynomial?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, analytic-number-theory, discriminant

Consider integer polynomials $P \in \mathbb{Z}[X] \setminus \{0\}$ of a degree $D \geq 1$ and without multiple complex roots. Let me introduce a notation
$$
d(P) := \frac{1}{D} \log{|\mathrm{Disc}(P)|}
$$
for the *logarithmic root discriminant* of $P$. An outstanding open problem is to prove (or disprove) that $d(P) \to \infty$ under any sequence of polynomials with degrees $D \to \infty$. Indeed it seems rare to have $d(P)$ much smaller than $\log{D}$; though that can certainly happen, since for instance $d(P) = \log{D} - \log{\log{D}} + \log{\log{\log{D}}} + O(1)$ when $P = \Phi_{p_1 \cdots p_k}$ is a cyclotomic polynomial of a level equal the product of the first $k$ primes (asymptotically as $k \to \infty$).

Let $\ell^1(P)$ be the sum of the absolute values of the coefficients of $P$.

**Question.** *Does 
$$
d(P) = \log{D} + O(\log{\ell^1(P)}),
$$
with an absolute implied coefficient?*

This is really about a lower bound on the discriminant of a polynomial with small integer coefficients; the explicit upper bound $d(P) \leq \log{D} + 2 \log{\ell^1(P)}$ is certainly known to hold for all polynomials, thanks to Mahler's classical inequality. Besides this rudimentary observation we note that the answer is certainly positive for all trinomials, thanks to an [explicit formula of Swan](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1103036322).

A part of this question is, in particular, whether all cyclotomic polynomials $P = \Phi_N$ have large enough coefficients to meet a discriminant lower bound
$$
d(P) - \log{D} \gg - \log{\ell^1(P)},
$$
which seems not immediately obvious. (What is the asymptotic for the $\ell^1$ norm of $\Phi_{p_1 \cdots p_k}$, where $2 = p_1 < p_2 < \cdots$ is the sequence of primes?)